# What happens underneath when timeout occurs with RxJava Observable.Callable

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactive

I'm working with a microservices and using RxJava in that. Just curious to know what happens underneath in RxJavA when a timeout occurs. Please consider the following example,

```
        Observable<Integer> dbOservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {code to get some DB data})
                .timeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                    System.out.println("dbOservable Timedout");
                    return record; //some dummy record
                });
```

Assume the DB query takes more than 60 seconds and as expected the timeout occurs. What's happening exactly underneath with RxJava this time?

Comment: What conclusion did you come to when you read the source?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I skimmed through the source code and found that the RxJava dispose the resources used for that particular callable. I'm not sure what is `resource` here though. My original question was what happens when an I/O request is fired but timed out before the response was received. My understanding is that the `Callable` thread fires up the network request and wait on the response, and dispose resources used for this operation just in case if the time out occurred during this time. And simply invokes the `onErrorReturn`.

Comment: The `timeout` operator starts a timer and subscribes to the upstream observable. If the timer fires, it unsubscribes from (disposes) the upstream observable which should cause it to cancel. It then emits using `onError()` to downstream.